# Prime number function C++

Tags: c++

I'm using filestreams, reading integers into an infile then reading those positive into an array directed to an outfile. I bubble sort the array and am required to find the average, variance, standard deviation, and prime numbers. I'm having trouble with my prime numbers function, it is not streaming anything into my file at all. [Photo of my terminal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T22bI.png). It's also miscalculating my average. I've taken out my sorting and get data functions so it doesn't look messy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 30;
void getVariance(int[], int);
bool isPrime(int[], int);
double average(int[], int);
int main()
{
  string inputfilename, outputfilename;
  ifstream infile;
  ofstream outfile;
  int prime, n, sum =0, posnumbers[MAX], countp=0, countn=0\
;
  double variance, stdv, avg=0;


  cout << "Please enter the name of the input file: ";
  cin >> inputfilename;
  infile.open(inputfilename.c_str());
  cout << "Please enter the name of the output file: ";
  cin >> outputfilename;

       ///////////////////////postive ////////////////////////////                            

  outfile.open(outputfilename.c_str());
  if(!infile)
    cout << "file not open for input" << endl;
  else
    {
     prime = isPrime(posnumbers, n);
     outfile << "=======================" << endl << endl;
     outfile << "Positive #'s in the File" << endl;
     for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
           if (posnumbers[i]>=0)
             {
               countp++;
               sum = sum + posnumbers[i];
               outfile << posnumbers[i] << endl;
               if (posnumbers[i] == prime)
                 outfile << posnumbers[i] << endl;
             }
         } 



     outfile << "average " <<  sum/n << endl;
     outfile << "variance " << variance << endl;


///////////////////////// functions/////////////////////                                 



bool isPrime(int posnum[], int n)
 {
   for (int i=2; i<=posnum[n]/2; i++)
     if (posnum[n] % i ==0)
       return false;
     else
       return true;
 }

double average(int posnum[], int n)
{
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      sum += posnum[n];
    }
  return sum / n;
}
```

Comment: `posnum[n]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of a buffer overrun. Valid indexes into an array of `n` elements are `0` through `n-1`

Comment: `isPrime` returns a boolean, which you convert to 0 or 1. In light of this, it's not clear what `posnumbers[i] == prime` check is supposed to achieve.

Comment: Your program doesn't read anything from `infile`. `posnumbers` is an uninitialized array containing random garbage. `n` is not initialized either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isPrime(int posnum[], int n)
 {
   for (int i=2; i<=posnum[n]/2; i++)
     if (posnum[n] % i ==0)
       return false;
     else
       return true;
 }
```

This will not work. The reason is that you immediately return true when the number is not divisible. For example, if `posnum[n]` is, let's say, 3, then your modulo check will fail and you are going to return true immediately, without checking all the other numbers that could potentially be divisors.

Furthermore, `isPrime` is currently checking only a single number for primality, but that isn't reflected in the calling code.

```
prime = isPrime(posnumbers, n);
```

Since `isPrime` returns `bool`, `prime` is now either 0 or 1.

```
if (posnumbers[i] == prime)
    outfile << posnumbers[i] << endl;
```

This means that that line will only output all numbers being 0 or 1, depending on the value of prime. You should call `isPrime` for every element of `posnumbers` instead and print it if it returns true.

For `isPrime`, try the following:

```
bool isPrime(int posnum[], int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= posnum[n] / 2; ++i) {
        if (posnum[n] % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In the for statement you wrote, when setting int i=0, I get a floating point exception error.

Comment: `if (prime == true)`
`{`
     `outfile << posnumbers[i] << endl;`
 `}`
is this what you mean?

Comment: @MeanDeanSayre Oops, the loop should start from i = 2. I overlooked that. As for you second question, yes, but you still need to call `isPrime` for every number in your array.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little bit confused on how to do that. I was thinking that...

`for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
         {
           if (posnumbers[i]>=0)
            {
               prime = isPrime(posnumbers, n);
            }
` 

was my call for each number in my array

Comment: @MeanDeanSayre Looks very promising. `prime = isPrime(posnumbers, n);` should be ` prime = isPrime(posnumbers, i);`, though, and you need to add the output logic, of course.

Comment: AH, I see what you mean now. Thank you!